# Ham sandwich for measuers implies the classical one

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Ham sandwich theorem for measures:

> Let $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3 $ be finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that every hyperplane has measure $0$ for each of $\mu_i$. Then there exists a hyperplane $h$ such that $\mu_i(h^+)= \frac{1}{2}\mu_i(\mathbb R^3)$ where $h^+$ denotes one of the half-space defined by $h$.

How does this theorem imply the classical ham sandwich theorem: Let $A,B,C$ be bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Then there is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ which divides each region exactly in half by volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure (the 'volume') in $\Bbb R^3$ and apply the theorem for

$\mu_1(X):=\lambda(X\cap A)$, $\ \mu_2(X):=\lambda(X\cap B)\ $ and $\ \mu_3(X):=\lambda(X\cap C)$.